# Mail::send laravel - How to access $message->to($variable);

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I'm using the function below to send Email:

```
public static function send_welcome_mail($user,$code)
{
    Mail::send('auth.email.welcome',['user'=>$user,'code'=>$code], function ($message)
    {
        $message->subject('Welcome');
        $message->from('info@example.com', 'Example');
        $message->to('info@exampleReceiver.com');
    });
}
```

Sending Email works fine , but when i change to this (add receiver):

```
public static function send_welcome_mail($user,$code,$receiver)
{
    Mail::send('auth.email.welcome',['user'=>$user,'code'=>$code], function ($message)
    {
        $message->subject('Welcome');
        $message->from('info@example.com', 'Example');
        $message->to($receiver);
    });
}
```

I got error:

> Undefined variable: receiverEmail

Comment: In your code, there is no `$receiverEmail` anywhere. Can you check it again?

Comment: Please show the code where you call the function send_welcome_email()

Answer (score 5):

You need to include that variable using `use` keyword

```
public static function send_welcome_mail($user,$code,$receiver)
{
    Mail::send('auth.email.welcome',
               ['user'=>$user,'code'=>$code], 
               function  ($message) use ($receiver) 
    {
        $message->subject('Welcome');
        $message->from('info@example.com', 'Example');
        $message->to($receiver);
    });
}
```